# wcf - Client Binding in Code- Error : "There was no endpoint listening at .svc that could accept the message."

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a webservice in wcf which have OperationContract like this :

```
[OperationContract]
string getDate(string id)
```

then I create a  client console project and added service reference with url of "http://localhost:58536/RealWorldServices/RealWorld.svc" and it completely work.

but i need to bind service reference in code. i used Svcutil.exe "webservice url" command in visual studio command prompt for creating "Service1.cs" . then I added it to my client console project. by adding these code to ot :

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:58536/ServiceReference1.IService1.svc");
Service1Client client = new Service1Client(binding, address);
string st = client.GetData("10");
```

but in last line which is exactly the same as calling method in previous way (adding in add webservice way) but I see I recieve this Error

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost:58536/ServiceReference1.IService1.svc that could
>   accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: IF you added a service reference to your project then why are you calling the service using an endpoint address?

The endpoint address should be automatically added in the config file while the service reference was added in your project..

just instantiate the proxy and call your method from the instance...

Comment: I don't want to use config setting. I just wrote that to say the service will work correctly in adding service. my problem is that client binding with code has error

Comment: Is this the baseAddress you mentioned in your service config file?
we don't use .svc extension in the service base address..

Comment: yes . It's this address : "http://localhost:58536/RealWorldServices/RealWorld.svc"

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be the issue??

In you example you are calling GetData:

```
string st = client.GetData("10");
```

But your contract says getDate

```
[OperationContract]
string getaDate(string id)
```

I believe one of the default methods created in the service is called GetData which accepts an `int`.

Comment: obviously the service is completely correct when it's work with add reference and your answer could not be true

Comment: @zohaatarodi Do you not see the error? you are calling the wrong method. GetDat`a`, GetData takes an integer. getDat`e` method takes a string.